# Visual Studio: every time I switch to a different Salesforce org it stays authenticated to the previous one

Tags: visual-studio, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I've been dealing with this issue for a while now, I most recently tried completely uninstalling VS code and reinstalling it and then going through and creating new SFDX project with manifest and authorizing yet the issue persists. Basically, if I have one org open, then close it (or if I keep it open and open a new VS code window with another org), every time I try to push changes or "open default org" it always opens the one from the previous org I had open (or the one I opened first if I have 2 VS code windows open).

So every time I switch to doing work for a different org I have to go and reauthenticate.

OS: Mac

I've been researching this issue but so far have not found a solution. Any advice around this would be helpful even if you aren't sure of the solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was related to conflicts between the ForceCode project I had made before switching to Source, and and SFDX project I'd created separately in the same dir. Deleting .forceCode and .sfdx and reinitializing resolved the issue for me.

Hope that's useful.